# Need to write Junit for a class

Tags: spring-boot, junit

```
public class abc(){

String s = "error";

Private Def def;

Public methodName(){

try
{
   List list = def.method();
   if(list == null)
   {
     Return something
   }
   else
   {
     Return something
   }
}

   catch(Exception e)
   {
       String error = s + e.getLocalizedMsg() + e.getCause();
       throw new CustomizedRuntimeException(error, e)
   }
}
}
```

I am able to cover for the lines inside TRY, but not sure about how to do for CATCH.

A little help would be so much valuable to me as I am new on this.

NOTE :- Junit version <= 4

Answer (score 0):

I guess your `def.method()` could throw an exception, right?

If `def` is a bean you can use [Mockito](https://site.mockito.org/) to inject a mock instead of a real instance and then declare what the method should return or throw. For Example:

```
when(def.method()).thenThrow(new Exception())
```

If you want to check for your `CustomizedRuntimeException` you can add that to your test annotation with `@Test(expected = CustomizedRuntimeException.class)`. That should cover your catch completely.

Comment: My def.method() returns a list by executing one query. And also need one clarification thay, after when(...) Do I need to have assert equals or anything like that ?

Comment: As you're throwing another exception, which is then explicitly expected by the test, you don't have to assert for this case (catch is covered). You just need to take care of your 'happy paths' also then

Comment: I mocked def, added expected(..) and also added when(..) as you suggested. But hetting error like, java.lang.exception: Unexoected exception. Expected customizedRuntimeException but was MockitoException.

Comment: As you tagged 'spring-boot', are those classes components/beans? If not this approach won't work. If so, please read a little bit about Mockito on how to initalise the mocks

Answer (score 0):

Create Def object as a mockbean using @MockBean and using Mockito mock the method() and then throw exception with a message. That's it.

Comment: Thank you. But can you provide a sample code for this ? I am completely new at this.